# Why need to assign a null value when using Constructor? Java

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, null

I noticed that in the below example code, when the "Scanner scan" and "String [] words" were declared, they were assigned 'null'. Why do we need to do that?  Many thanks for your help! * The example code was designed to read strings from a file, with the first line of the file being the number of strings: int howMany.

```
int howMany;
Scanner scan = null;  //why do we need to assign a 'null'?  
File f;
String[] words = null; //why not use String[] words= new String []; ?

try {
   f = new File(filename);
   scan= new Scanner(f); 
   howMany = scan.nextInt(); 
   words = new String[howMany];

   for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
     words[i] = scan.next();
   }
} catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e); 
}
```

Comment: You don't have to, its just a bad practice to leave things as "default". Making it explicit is often more clear.

Comment: Local variables are not initialised to a default value, this forces you to provide a "known" value to them to help prevent weird and un-repeatable results ;)

Comment: In both cases it would have made more sense to define and initialize the variables at a later point in the code, for example, when 'howMany' is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, why initialize the Scanner to null?  Assume you didn't.  In your code example, this wouldn't matter much, but what if you wanted to use the Scanner object after the try block, in the catch or finally blocks, or return it from method?  The Scanner might not have been initialized, since you (and the compiler) doesn't necessarily know what will happen in the try block until runtime.  It's not a necessity to instantiate the Scanner to null, it is just common place to instantiate IO objects to null outside of try blocks because you will usually have to do something with that IO object outside of the try block, namely, close it.
Secondly: 
    "why not use String[] words= new String []; ?"
Because array initializers require an amount between the '[' and the ']' and the amount is derived from the scan.nextInt(); execution line.  Why is it being initialized to null?  Se the first paragraph.
It is a good philosophy/strategy to not declare objects until they are needed to limit scope, and as an extension, it is good not to initialize objects until needed.  Setting either of these to null preemptively will cause more harm than good and opens you up to NPEs.  Java will initialize array components, class variables and instance variables to null by default.  If the variable does not fall into this category, then leave it uninitialized unless the first paragraph situation forces you to do otherwise, as the compiler will warn you if it is used without being first initialized (this is a protective mechanism for you, the developer)
So to answer your question, you don't need to do that in the given example, and probably shouldn't.